# Parsing HTML in Delphi to find the addresses of all images

Tags: html, xml, delphi, pascal

How can I extract the addresses of all images in an HTML file using Delphi, for example by using an HTML parser?

Comment: Here's a rough translation to English:  "hello how to recover the source of all images in an html page in delphi? I seek to recover all the images in an HTML page using an html parser in Delphi.
thank you"

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`IHTMLDocument2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface to parse the HTML, check this sample [`Retrieving all image links from an HTML document`](http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2004/a/bltip1204_3.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The JVCL has a component, JvHtmlParser, that might work for you.

I have successfully used it to extract data from tables in HTML files.

The TIpHtml class in the old TurboPower Internet Professional VCL component library that "implements parsing and rendering of HTML documents".  It is old, does not appear to have been updated since 2003.